# Calculating the size of a capacitor in a sample and hold circuit

Tags: capacitor, adc, noise

**Question**: *In sampling system the sample rate is 500 Ms/s with an input signal of range of 1 V peak−peak and a clock jitter of 1 ps rms . A performance of 60 dB is required for all signals the Nyquist baseband. Calculate its size of the capacitor.*

**My solution**

First, I calculate the jitter power with an equation given in the book 
[image]
Next, I calculate the signal power 
[image]
Now, I know that SNR = Psignal/(Pjitter + PthermalNoise), 
[image]

**However, I seem to be getting a negative value for the thermal noise power??** My plan was to use this thermal noise power and equate it to kT/C to get my capacitor size. But the thermal power is negative?? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Rearranging your SNR equation went wrong.

Comment: You went a little crazy with the significant digits in your first equation. Just because your calculator gives you ten digits doesn't mean they are all reliable.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Hmm. I just checked it again. what step in the rearranging did I go wrong? Pthermal = Psignal/SNR - Pjitter

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Apologies, a bit of a bad habit after being stung a few times in some online tests for "inaccuracy"

Comment: The rearrangment of the SNR equation is correct

Comment: My apologies, I was misreading the scribble. I agree it is correct. Now if your jitter power calculation is correct, the implication is that jitter alone exceeds your SNR budget leaving no budget for thermal noise at any capacitance.